# Установить текст в TextView в адаптере

Tags: getview, android, listview, java

Вот мой адаптер:

```
public View getView(int i, View someView, ViewGroup arg2) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if (someView == null) {
        someView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user_listview, arg2, false);
    }

    final TextView header1 = (TextView) someView.findViewById(R.id.Name);
    final TextView header2 = (TextView) someView.findViewById(R.id.Doljnost);
    header1.setText(data.get(i).header1);
    header2.setText(data.get(i).header2);

    final CheckBox box = (CheckBox)someView.findViewById(R.id.Box);
    box.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (box.isChecked())
            {        
                header1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#458B00"));

            } else
            {
                  header1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4df33f"));
            }

        }

    });

    return someView;
}
```

Я хочу при клике на CheckBox в Listview установить текст в TextView, который находится в другой разметке, которая выгядит так:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/headText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Пользователи"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

<ListView
android:layout_below="@+id/search_user"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/lvUsers"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/listview_users">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Возможно ли это сделать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что мешает к примеру в конструкторе адаптера передать этот самый **TextView** и в коллбеке выставлять текст?

Comment: получилось! спасибо большое.

Comment: чёрт, юзай ViewHolder, без него грустно на это смотреть :) а вообще можно сделать то что ты хочешь, ток я не подскажу, потому что нефига не понял )

Comment: пожалуйста.
@urikor, на счет паттерна ViewHolder тоже стоило бы почитать статейки.